# TC problem 5-2:how to calculate the probability of the indicator random variable?

Tags: algorithm

Here is the original problem:

> Now consider a deterministic linear search algorithm, which we refer to as
> DETERMINISTIC-SEARCH. Specifically, the algorithm searches  for  in order,
> considering [1],[2],A[3]...[] until either it finds [] =  or it reaches
> the end of the array. Assume that all possible permutations of the input array are
> equally likely.
>
> (e) Suppose that there is exactly one index  such that [] = . What is the
> average-case running time of DETERMINISTIC-SEARCH? What is the worstcase running time of DETERMINISTIC-SEARCH?
>
> (f) Generalizing your solution to part (e), suppose that there are  ≥ 1 indices 
> such that [] = . What is the average-case running time of DETERMINISTICSEARCH? What is the worst-case running time of DETERMINISTIC-SEARCH?
>
> Your answer should be a function of  and .

I can find the answer to (f) on the website:

> The worst-case running time is −+1. The average-case running time is (+1)/(+1). Let  be an indicator random variable that the <sup>th</sup> element is a match. Then Pr() is 1/(+1)

Why the Pr() is like this?

> Let  be an indicator random variable that we have found a match after the first −+1 elements (Pr() = 1)
>
> Thus () = (<sub>1</sub> + <sub>2</sub> + ... + <sub>−</sub> + )
>
> = 1 + <sub>=1</sub>∑<sup>−</sup> ()
>
> = 1 + ( − ) / ( + 1)
>
> = ( + 1) / ( + 1)

Why they split  into <sub>1</sub> , ... , <sub>−</sub> , ?

Comment: What is "TC"? I suggest you provide a link to the original statement of the problem. I expect your question will not be well-received here if you do not provide evidence of your efforts to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: What is "5-2"? What is "the website"?

Comment: Perhaps this is a better match for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If Pr() is the probability that the -th index has a match, then the quoted statement that Pr()=1/(+1) is wrong. That probability decreases the greater the array is, so it should be dependent on . But without a source reference, and without definition of what all these abbreviations mean, there is not much we can say.